# Masstransit - Scheduling a recurring message that support multitenancy

Tags: multi-tenant, masstransit

I would like use Masstransit scheduling API for multi tenant application. I need to send recurring messages per tenant.

```
var schedule1 = new MySchedule("1 * * * * ?", "Tenant 1");
var schedule2 = new MySchedule("6 * * * * ?", "Tenant 2");

endPoint.Result.ScheduleRecurringSend(sendToUri, schedule1, new OrderCommand
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Name = "Tenant 1"
});

endPoint.Result.ScheduleRecurringSend(sendToUri, schedule2, new OrderCommand
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Name = "Tenant 2"
});


public class MySchedule : DefaultRecurringSchedule
{
    public MySchedule(string cronExpression, string description)
    {
        CronExpression = cronExpression;
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the scheduler uses class name "MyScheduler" as a job name and can't send two recurring messages using MyScheduler. Is there a way to implement multitenancy with Masstransit scheduling API?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `ScheduleId` and/or `ScheduleGroup` in your constructor (for your `MySchedule` class) to be tenant-specific, and it will change the identifier used by Quartz.

```
public class MySchedule : DefaultRecurringSchedule
{
    public MySchedule(string cronExpression, string description, string tenantId)
    {
        CronExpression = cronExpression;
        Description = description;

        ScheduleId = "MyScheduleForTenant" + tenantId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. I have to use RecurringSchedule interface instead of DefaultRecurringSchedule and it changes Quartz identifier.